# How can I solve the 'Cannot set property 'myInterval' of undefined' error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So, the error says Cannot set property 'myInterval' of undefined and I don't know why. Also, I can send you a full version of the code, if it is needed

```
const timerStart = () => {
          this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
          setIsOn(true);
    
          if (secs > 0) {
```

Comment: It means that `this` is `undefined` and that's because you are using [`this` within an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which doesn't change the `this` binding. You should try passing an anonymous function instead so that `this` will take on its own invocation context.

Answer (score 1):

Change `this.myInterval` to `const myInterval`

To have acces to the `myInterval` varialbe outside of the function you can declare it in a `constructor` at the top of the component like this

```
class MyComponent extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myInterval = null;
    }
    

    setInterval = () => {
        this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("Running interval");
        }, 1000);
    };

    cancelInterval = () => clearInterval(this.myInterval);

    render() {
        return "..."
    }

}
```

Comment: now I can't use myInterval anywhere else, only in timerStart function. Is there a method to fix that?

Comment: I updated my answer again with a more proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

and do not forget if you want to use a function you definde within your class component, you need to bind this to your component!

and if you are using functional component easily just use **const** and define your function

```
// Class Component 
hello(){

}
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.hello = this.hello.bind(this)
}

//Function Component 

const hello =() =>{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timerStart = setInterval( callback, time );
```

You don't have to call a function on the `timerStart` variable. It will automatically start the timer for you.

Of course if that's what you want to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use **this** keyword inside an arrow function.

Solution: remove the **this** keyword, and make it **const**

```
const timerStart = () => {
   const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
       ... your code ...
   }
}
```

the issue is, as per your comment: **now I can't use myInterval anywhere else, only in timerStart function. Is there a method to fix that?**

Solution: you can make a function separate for **setInterval**, then you can call it anywhere.

```
const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
   ... your code ...
   if (somecodition) {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
   }
},1000)
```

now use this **myInterval** anywhere you want with 1000 ms gap the function will run (see clearInterval is also there with any condition you want )

call the function whenever you want to run  : `myInterval()`